# Transfer files over XMPP using SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp

I want to develop a Python XMPP client primarily for transferring files and some IMs too. I have been researching on the web. I've found many Stack Overflow users recommending SleekXMPP for Python.

I need to know if sleekXMPP supports file transfers. Some people say it's possible, others say it's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SleekXMPP has [a module](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/blob/master/sleekxmpp/plugins/xep_0096/file_transfer.py) that supports [XEP-0096 (SI File Transfer)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html), so the answer is that it does support file transfers.

Comment: Thanks! You know where to find examples? I can't find it.

Comment: @Faisal, Did you find the examples for sending files through sleekxmpp, If you got please share it.I am also having trouble in finding examples.Thanks in advance!